# What does "has a laser on" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

https://twitter.com/NateSilver538/status/1324714715872972800 says

> The Electoral College has a laser on Joe Biden.

They  believed EC was bad especially four years ago, but praising EC because it helps this time will back fire. So what do people usually mean by "have a laser on"? (I have never seen it is used before)

Comment: Nate Silver isn't operating on a lot of sleep these days, so I wouldn't necessarily expect all of his tweets to make complete sense just now.

Comment: There is nothing that people **usually** mean by it; it was an one-off metaphor, so analysing it would not illuminate any general feature of the language.

Comment: It's not an idiomatically established usage, but presumably the reference is to the [***laser sights***](https://uk.dhgate.com/laser-rifle-sight-uk.html) on some rifles. *The Electoral College has Joe Biden **in their sights*** = *they're "gunning" for him*.

Answer (score 3):

“Has a laser on” isn’t a generally used expression. It is a reference to one particular prior tweet by a sports reporter who was trying to come up with a creative way to reveal draft picks while maintaining a pretense of plausible deniability:

> During the 2018 NBA Draft, reporters were asked not to tip picks in advance. Wojnarowski heeded this request until the New York Times’s Marc Stein began revealing the selections moments before they were announced.
>
> So Wojnarowski countered by leaning on an assortment of clever verbs and adjectives as his loophole for revealing his scoops: “Source: Portland has a laser on Anfernee Simons,’’ he tweeted.

(“[What to make of ESPN reporter Adrian Wojnarowski’s exchange with Missouri Senator Josh Hawley](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.boston.com/sports/media/2020/07/15/adrian-wojnarowski-espn-suspension/amp)”, By Chad Finn, July 15, 2020)

(Silver is well known to be a sports fan.)
That is, it’s an allusion to an intentionally oddly worded tweet. The meaning is most likely that Silver wants to indicate that he thinks Biden will take the Electoral College, but doesn’t want to directly call the race yet.